# How do I configure nginx to reverse proxy based on the Accept header?

Tags: nginx, headers, http-proxy

Suppose I have nginx reverse proxying to a local HTTP server.

If I want everything under /wombat, I can do that with

```
    location /wombat {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/marnanel/whatever.sock;
    }
```

But how would I go about telling nginx to reverse proxy according to the MIME type requested in the `Accept` header?

Something like

```
    accept image/* {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/marnanel/whatever.sock;
    }
```

only not that, because I just made it up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` to map Accept header value to variable based on condition (in this case i'm checking for `"application/json"` Accept header

```
map $http_accept $upstream_value {
    default "app_upstream";
    "application/json" "foo_upstream";
}
```

and then

```
proxy_pass http://$upstream_value/;
```